# Error with DrawerLayout and RelativeLayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have `RelativeLayout` within `DrawerLayout` this is my xml file:

## Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
            android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/layer_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#14ad8f"
           >

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
                    style="@style/ButtonRed"
                    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/close_button_container"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Nosaukums"
                android:id="@+id/fragNosaukums" />
        </RelativeLayout>



    </com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />





    <!--android:name="com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.NavigationDrawerFragment"-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is my java code:

## MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private String urlJsonObj = "http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_object.json";
    private String urlJsonArry = "http://heimerdinger.pe.hu/getjson.php";
    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Content content = new Content();
    public static String valueEntered;
    private String jsonResponse;
    private SlidingLayer mSlidingLayer;
    private TextView swipeText, fragNosaukums;
    public String name;
    public Marker marker;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));




       // fragNosaukums = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fragNosaukums);

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.getUiSettings();
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        bindViews();
        initState();

        mSlidingLayer.bringToFront();

        redirect();


        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                marker.showInfoWindow();
                String title = marker.getTitle();

                fragNosaukums.setText(title);
                mSlidingLayer.openLayer(true);

                return true;
            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }








    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        }
    }

    /**
     * View binding
     */
    private void bindViews() {
        mSlidingLayer = (SlidingLayer) findViewById(R.id.slidingLayer1);
//        swipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.swipeText);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the origin state of the layer
     */
    private void initState() {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        setupSlidingLayerPosition(prefs.getString("layer_location", "right"));

        setupShadow(prefs.getBoolean("layer_has_shadow", false));
        setupLayerOffset(prefs.getBoolean("layer_has_offset", false));
        setupPreviewMode(prefs.getBoolean("preview_mode_enabled", false));
    }

    private void setupSlidingLayerPosition(String layerPosition) {

        DrawerLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mSlidingLayer.getLayoutParams();
        int textResource;
        Drawable d;

//        if (layerPosition.equals("right")) {
            textResource = R.string.swipe_right_label;
            d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.container_rocket_right);

            mSlidingLayer.setStickTo(SlidingLayer.STICK_TO_RIGHT);


        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
//        swipeText.setCompoundDrawables(null, d, null, null);
//        swipeText.setText(getResources().getString(textResource));
        mSlidingLayer.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    }

    private void setupShadow(boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
            mSlidingLayer.setShadowSizeRes(R.dimen.shadow_size);
            mSlidingLayer.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.sidebar_shadow);
        } else {
            mSlidingLayer.setShadowSize(0);
            mSlidingLayer.setShadowDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    private void setupLayerOffset(boolean enabled) {
        int offsetDistance = enabled ? getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset_distance) : 0;
        mSlidingLayer.setOffsetDistance(offsetDistance);
    }

    private void setupPreviewMode(boolean enabled) {
        int previewOffset = enabled ? getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.preview_offset_distance) : -1;
        mSlidingLayer.setPreviewOffsetDistance(previewOffset);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
//        case R.id.buttonOpen:
//            mSlidingLayer.openLayer(true);
//            break;
//        case R.id.buttonClose:
//            mSlidingLayer.closeLayer(true);
//            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (mSlidingLayer.isOpened()) {
                mSlidingLayer.closeLayer(true);
                return true;
            }

        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.addNewEvent:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddEvent.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                ;

            case android.R.id.home:
                //Do stuff
                //mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                return true;
        }


        return true;
    }



}
```

And this is the error I get when i run the app.

## LogCat

```
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): Process: com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample, PID: 6607
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample/com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1126)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1331)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-18 17:39:13.878: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

It haven't really faced this problem before. I tried to change RelativeLayout and DrawerLayout with places but it didn't work. I guess the problem might be in java file. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using the wrong `LayoutParams` class; are you importing `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` per chance?
`LayoutParams` differ per type of `Layout`. Use `DrawerLayout.LayoutParams` where the casting error is thrown (line 255), that should work. It should look like this:

```
DrawerLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mSlidingLayer.getLayoutParams();`
```

Comment: It did not change anything

Comment: Can you debug that line and check what type `mSlidingLayer` is?